# OOP with method chaining in PHP

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, method-chaining

First of all - my English is bad so I hope you will understand. I have question involving method chaining on nested objects structure.

I'm trying to create some kind of a list with objects and sub lists that create itself on the fly. So far i have this code:

```
interface IData {}


class root {
    public function __construct( root $proxy = null ) {
        $this->proxy = $proxy;
    }
    public function __destruct() {
        if( !is_null( $this->proxy ) ) {
            unset( $this->proxy );
        }
    }
    public function OpenList() {
        $list = new field_list( $this );
        $this->data[] = $list;
        return $list;
    }

    public function CloseList() {
        return $this->proxy;
    }

    public function Add() {
        $this->data[] = new field();
        return $this;
    }


    private $proxy = null;
    private $data = array();
}

class field_list extends root implements IData {
    public function __construct( root $proxy ) {
        parent::__construct( $proxy );
    }
    public function __destruct() {
         parent::__destruct();
    }
}

class field implements IData {}
```

I'm using my code as follows:

```
$root = new root();
$root->OpenList()->Add()->CloseList()->OpenList()->Add()->Add()->Add()->OpenList()->Add();
```

I can append to $root field objects (`class field`), but also open new lists (`class field_list`) and append field objects to the last opened list.

I wonder if the object reference i created (`$proxy`) will cause memory leak problems, and also if there are any performance issues with this code. (EDIT:) when i `print_r($root);` I'm getting *recursion* in the output, and I don't know if it's some type of a problem with my objects structure.

```
root Object(
[proxy:root:private] => 
[data:root:private] => Array
    (
        [0] => field_list Object
            (
                [proxy:root:private] => root Object
  *RECURSION*
                [data:root:private] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => field Object
                            (
                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => field_list Object
            (
                [proxy:root:private] => root Object
  *RECURSION*
                [data:root:private] => Array
                    (
                       ........
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Thank you

Comment: How long does your script work? And why should it cause leaks?

Comment: @zerkms I've edited my question. Hope you could explain the *RECURSION* issue. thank you

Comment: The worst part of this post from an English language point of view is your first sentence.  "my English is bad" is incorrect usage.  Secondly, if you use English better than native speakers, and say "my English is bad" it comes across as condescending and offensive. I have no idea why so many non-native speakers insist on using this phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen chained method calls before, and I don't think that I've ever encountered any issues. In terms of memory leaks, I doubt there is a problem because unlike in languages like C++ or Java, you don't have to deal with the memory. You've taken care to write a destructor, so I doubt there will be a problem.

Since you are creating only 1 instance, it should only refer to 1 instance of the property $proxy, so I'm thinking this could be OK.